# ExtJS qtip is not getting displayed

Tags: javascript, regex, extjs4

I have a grid panel and im trying to display a hover popup on a particular column. I have tried both tooltip and qtip but they are just not getting displayed. My grid panel looks as:

```
Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
        id: 'frPanel-'+interfaceId,
        store: frStore,
        columns : [ {text : 'Source',
            dataIndex : 'source',
            renderer : function(value) {
                return convertObjValue(value);
            },
            listeners: {
                afterrender: function ()
                {
                    Ext.create('Ext.tip.ToolTip',
                    {
                        target: this.el,
                        trackMouse: true,
                        html: "Hello there"
                    });
                }
            }
        }, {
            text : 'Destination',
            dataIndex : 'destination',
            menuDisabled : true,
            renderer : function(value, metaData) {
                var newValue = convertObjValue(value);
                metaData.tdAttr = 'data-qtip="' + newValue + '"';
                return newValue;
            }
        }
```

What am i doing wrong here? Any help how i can achieve this?

**EDIT :** So i made the second column work by adding `Ext.QuickTips.init();` in the onReady() function. But i still wanna know how to make it work using the approach in first column.

Comment: In the past whenever I've added tooltips to a grid I've used your second, working method. There's nothing wrong with it, although it's not the prettiest solution.

Comment: @Lesley.Oakey I understand why you are saying that and i like it too. But the problem here is i wanna make an ajax call add display a list of values in that tooltip. Can i achieve it using that?

Comment: Ah, I see. Yes you'll need the Ext.create method then. I haven't really used this method so can't help much but a good starting point, if you haven't already seen it, is http://try.sencha.com/extjs/4.0.7/examples/qtips/qtips/. It features an Ajax tooltip and hopefully the process will help you!